# Multiply 1D list to 2D list but only the same index

Tags: python, list, indexing, list-comprehension, nested-lists

I have 2 list like this
d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
c = [1,2,3]

so i want to multiply only one each element of c to only one list inside d. Like this:
y1 = c[0] x d[0] = [1x1, 1x2, 1x3]
y2 = c[1] x d[1] = [2x4, 2x5, 2x6]
y3 = c[2] x d[2] = [3x7, 3x8, 3x9]

And then append it to a new 2D list [[y1],[y2],[y3]].

Expected process: [ [1x1, 1x2, 1x3], [2x4, 2x5, 2x6], [3x7, 3x8, 3x9] ]
Anyone knows how to do it? thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a list comprehension, if you want a pure Python solution:

```py
d = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
c = [1,2,3]

print([[d[row][col] * c[row] for col in range(len(d[0])] for row in range(len(d))])
```

This can also be more concisely achieved using `numpy`:

```py
import numpy as np

d = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
c = np.array([1,2,3])

print(d * c[:, np.newaxis])
```